# SQuirreL (SQL) fails to load with IllegalStateException

Tags: jdbc, illegalstateexception, squirrel-sql

SQuirreL (SQL) will fail to load with the following stack trace.

```
ERROR net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main  - Exception occurred dispatching Event java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main$$Lambda$7/1937962514@213d039,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1600348904062] on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@22834772
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not create bundle before locale was initalized.
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main.doApplicationStartup(Main.java:124)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main.lambda$startApp$0(Main.java:111)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not create bundle before locale was initalized.
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.resources.LazyResourceBundle.getString(LazyResourceBundle.java:34)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be caused by corrupted configuration files in `%USERPROFILE%\.squirrel-sql`.

1. Validate each config file
2. Delete corrupted files
3. Run SQuirreL

In Notepad++ corrupted files will contain `NUL`.

Comment: I had the same problem, where every file contained `NUL`. This was fixed by deleting the whole folder `%USERPROFILE%\.squirrel-sql` and running `squirrel-sql.bat` again.